# Simple proof that entangled pure states are not separable

Tags: entanglement, density-matrix, purification, quantum-state

I am trying to understand more about the notion of separable states. For clarity, I will only use the word *entangled* for pure states, even if a non-separable state is sometimes called entangled too.

- Where could I find a simple proof that pure, entangled states are not separable? The only I found is a [sketch of proof](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17709/does-the-definition-of-separability-of-pure-states-require-the-components-of-the) that involves the notion of *RHS rank* and I do not understand its meanings. Is it linked to the Schmidt decomposition of the state?
- Is there a simple example of a state that is neither pure nor
  separable?
- Is it true that a state is non-separable only if any of its purification is entangled? (Same for: separable if and only if any of its purification is a product).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: RHS refers to "right-hand side", as in the expression on the right side of the '=' sign in an equation that is being referred to.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/643655/58382

Answer (score 2):

> simple proof that pure, entangled states are not separable

You won't find a proof. It's a matter of definition. We **define** entanglement by the statement "a state is entangled if it is not separable".

> Is there a simple example of a state that is neither pure nor separable

Sure! The states $(1-p)I/4+p|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ where $|\psi\rangle=(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ are easily proven to be entangled for a range of parameters $p$ (exercise: what range?) using the partial transpose criterion.

> a state is non-separable only if any of its purification is entangled

If it is non-separable, it is already entangled. No purification required (but yes, a purification would contain entanglement because an action such as tracing out a qubit cannot increase the entanglement present). However, the other direction is not true - if you have an entangled purification, it does not mean that the state is entangled (see next point).

> a state is separable if and only if any of its purification is a product

This is false. Any separable mixed state will have an entangled purification. (If the purification is separable, you have a product state. That means that when you trace out the extra system, you're left with a pure separable state. Hence the purification of mixed separable states is not a separable state, and is therefore entangled.)