What is the minimum number of separable states (not necessarily pure) needed to decompose arbitrary separable states?
For a bipartite separable quantum state $\rho$ acting on Hilbert space $H\otimes H'$ with $\dim H=D$ and $\dim 
 H'=D'$, what is the minimum number of separable state needed for a decomposition?  That is, what is the smallest $r$ such that
$$\rho=\sum_{i=1}^r A_i\otimes B_i.$$
The problem was widely studied, if you require the decomposition to be pure, i.e.,  $A_i$ and $B_i$ are pure.  A general upper bound for  that is $D^2D'^{2}$ (Though for qubit-qubit state, it is 4. )
I am wondering, what if one removes the requirement of $A_i$ and $B_i$ being pure, how does the upper bound change?

related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13031/55

Thanks for including the URL,  this post is about decomposition into pure product states,   and my main question is to understand a general decomposition without pure-state-constrain.  Or if there is a way to see that they are equivelaent.

They're not equivalent. Suppose $\rho$ is the maximally mixed state of two qubits. Then by simply considering the rank of the operators we find $r=4$ with the pure state constraint and $r=1$ without it.
